# android - time difference

Tags: java, android, time

I have looked at the other Q&A regarding this subject but didn't find anything that helped.

My app records race results and saves to file.

On 1st click it writes the current time, and when a runner is finished, it records the current time again.

How can I calculate both times to get race time?

Here is how I get the current time:

```
public class Stopwatch extends Activity {
// GUI controls
Button startRun;
Button checkIn;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setRequestedOrientation(
        ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        setContentView(R.layout.stopwatch); 

        final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");


         startRun = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
        startRun.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("/sdcard/timer.txt"));
            out.write("Race start time" + "," + dateFormat.format(new Date()));
            out.write("\r\n");
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        startRun.setEnabled(false);

    }
    });

        checkIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.counter);
        checkIn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            private int entryCounter = 1;

        public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("/sdcard/timer.txt", true));
            out.write(entryCounter +  "," + dateFormat.format(new Date()) + "," ***time difference here***);
            entryCounter++;
            out.write("\r\n");
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

    }
    });



    }
```

}

i am looking for a format like this

```
0,01/10/2011 09:02:00
1,01/10/2011 09:18:42,00:16:42
2,01/10/2011 09:18:42,00:16:42
3,01/10/2011 09:20:07,00:18:07
```

Comment: Do you want to subtract the times to get the elapsed time?

Comment: Yes, i need to subtract the start time from the lap time to get run time. but it needs to print out it that format. my code does it all apart from the run time

Answer (score 3):

You should use the method currentTimeMillis()

```
long millisecondssince1970 = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

after that you can get the new time and calculate the difference

```
long newTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
long raceTimeinMilliseconds = newTime - millisecondssince1970;
```

In addition to this you can use the getTime() method of Date objects to do this. This method returns a millisecond value as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
// ... the race 
long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
long raceDurationInMillis = end - start;
```

You may be more precise and use System.nanoTime, but I doubt it will make a significant difference.

Comment: so how would i write that into thischeckIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.counter);
      checkIn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
       
       private int entryCounter = 1;

      public void onClick(View v) {
   try {
       BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("/sdcard/timer.txt", true));
       out.write(entryCounter +  "," + dateFormat.format(new Date()) + "," [difference to go here]);
       entryCounter++;
       out.write("\r\n");
       out.close();
   } catch (Exception e) {
   }

  }// onClick
  }); // btnWriteSDFile